# Possible to load external jpg and serve as local url? Redirect w/o .htaccess?

Tags: html, image, .htaccess, redirect

I'm hosting images for client websites. I want them to be able to link to the images locally ie. www.myclient.com/clip1.jpg but have the image actually loaded from www.mysite.com/clip1.jpg. The idea is to provide security/anonyminity so the client doesn't have to reveal that they are using my service (through the images on my site).

Can this be done without editing .htaccess?

Thanks,
skibulk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to reveal where the final origin is, then the image has to come from the server that you want it to appear to come from. A redirect will reveal the real origin.

You can proxy the images with with [Apache directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), the equivalent for whatever non-Apache server is in use, or a server side script (written in the language of your choice that is supported by the server).

Just copying the images would probably be the most efficient approach though.

Comment: I think I would prefer to host the images myself, because it gives my client one more reason to use my service, and keeps them from developing their own database out of mine. But then again I suppose since they have access to the images they could just save them all using a script anyway...